# Why do I get an 404 Error after using TYPO3 V9.5

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-404, multilingual, typo3-9.x

I am using TYPO3 9.5 and I created a root page with several subpages.
Before I created a site configuration the subpages were available as

```
/index.php?id=19
```

after the site configuration the url has changed to

```
/events
```

which is absolutely fine but my subpage cannot be found anymore. I get an 404 Error.

The subpage is still available under the old url but the new one doesn't work.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

after changing the slug(path/path segment) for a page you need to update the slugs for all subpages manually.

The slug is generated automatically when the page is created. Probably your slugs were generated wrong before you build your site configuration.
Try to autogenerate all the slugs with the adapted wizard. You must do it by hand for each page as there is no wizard for page subtrees (yet). you might do the multi-edit in the list module for the slug field.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and no clue how to solve. See [TYPO3 9.5 URL Routing with URL Segment is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515202/typo3-9-5-url-routing-with-url-segment-is-not-working)

Manual slug override, saving, chache clearance etc. does not help.

Are you using as well Apache? Maybe the issue is related to the webserver.

Comment: My issue is solved now, was misconfigured Apache2 (AllowOverride was missing). Details see issue above.