# TYPO3 9.5 URL Routing with URL Segment is not working

Tags: url-routing, typo3-9.x

I am not very experienced in Typo3 so I hope my question/problem would be a quite simple one.

I use a Typo3 9.5.0 LTS instanz on Ubuntu with Apache and MySQL.

Problem is that URLS routing (https://typo3.org/community/teams/typo3-development/initiatives/routing/) is not working.

I created a Site Configuration for relevant Pagetree. Within the pages in Backend the URL segment is visible and changeable. This URL segment is also taken correct by menu entries and by the sitemap.

But I could not access the pages with that path (get 404).

to summarize:

- `/index.php?id=[URL Segment]` works fine.
- `/index.php?id=[ID#]` works fine.
- `/[URL Segment]` does not work. Apache creates 404

I have no routeenhacers in yaml site config active and cleared already the cache.

It would be great if someone has an idea where to dig deeper to solve that issue.

Thanks
yES

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess config? Is mod_rewrite enabled? See https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess for an example.

Comment: Good point, Thanks for the hint.But I use so far poor standard typo3 .htaccess file without modifications. So yes rewrite engine is on and rest is also default settings.

Comment: And the 404 is the Apache error page not a TYPO3 site? then something seems to be wrong with the apache configuration / .htaccess - can you post the relevant parts of your httpd.conf? (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#apache for requirements)

Comment: You are my Hero of the day and I apologize to be to dump to rtfm. AllowOverride was missing now everything runs smoth.

Comment: I was a little to fast. I dont get a 404 anymore but now every path like "/[URL Segment]" or "/completenonsense111" is redirected to the root page instead of the corresponding URL Segment-page.

Comment: Finally I found cause for the strange behavior. When I change within the Site Configuration the protokol from https to http its working fine.